# Cakephp 2.6.1, PHPExcel "Unable to load PDF Rendering library"

Tags: cakephp, pdf, phpexcel

On the same project i'm using phpExcel to generate excel files just fine.

PHPExcel files location:

C:\wamp\www\circulo\app\Vendor\PHPExcel\ (this folder contains PHPExcel.php along with PHPExcel files folder)

Also on the same project, i'm using dompdf alone to generate pdf file just fine (not via PHPExcel). I've just liked a lot how PHPExcel allows excel file construction so i'd like to create pdfs via PHPExcel as well.

dompdf files location:

C:\wamp\www\circulo\app\Vendor\dompdf\

The path seems correct via debugger => C:\wamp\www\circulo\app\Vendor\dompdf\dompdf.php

This is my code to get a pdf file:
I get error: 
[PHPExcel_Writer_Exception] Unable to load PDF Rendering library

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

require_once APP . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'PHPExcel' . DS . 'PHPExcel.php';

$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF; 
$rendererLibrary = 'dompdf.php'; 
$rendererLibraryPath = APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS  .$rendererLibrary;
Debugger::log($rendererLibraryPath);

if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(   $rendererName,   $rendererLibraryPath  )) {  die(   'Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .   PHP_EOL .   ' as appropriate for your directory structure' . $rendererLibraryPath  ); } 

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($objPHPExcel); 
//$objWriter->save("emptyPdfJustYet.pdf");
```

Tried their demo 21pdf.php to same results.

Can you help? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

When I print the error to log, I realize it is trying to load the dompdf_config.inc.php from an invalid location. See below.

C:\wamp\www\myapp\app\Vendor\dompdf\dompdf.php/dompdf_config.inc.php\n

Rather than altering the class files of PHPExcel, it's wise to change the configuration in your view. Ignoring the $rendererLibrary completely in the $rendererLibraryPath fixed my issue. I think the PHPExcel know how to pick dompdf.php file. Try below code let us know if it doesn't work.

And you are providing wrong render constant too, changed PDF_RENDERER_MPDF to PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF.

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF; 
$rendererLibrary = 'dompdf.php'; 
$rendererLibraryPath = APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf';
```

And for create writer object, I tried

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
```